# How to Horizontally Center React Native Flexbox Text that Wraps across Multiple Lines

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

In React Native, using flexbox, text in my `<Text>` components are centered Horizontally (and vertically).

This works as expected -- ***if*** line of text is short enough that it does **not** need to **wrap** onto the next line.

But, when given a **long text** string, that **wraps** across multiple lines, the rendered text does **not center horizontally** !
Instead the wrapped text is aligned to the left edge.

How can I force wrapped lines of text to center horizontally ?

This horizontally centers `shortText`, but not `longText`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class Deck extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const shortText = 'Centered!';  
    const shortText = 'This very long line of text does NOT Center. Instead the wrapped text is aligned to the left edge of the container.';         

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.titleText}> {shortText} </Text>
          <Text style={styles.titleText}> {longText}  </Text>
        </View>   
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 27,
    flexWrap: 'wrap', 
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});
```

Note: I find *plenty* of Stack Overflow questions/answers, and blog posts
 for *Vertical* centering, and *Horizontal* centering when the text does *Not wrap* onto multiple "lines".
But I have been unable to find any for centering *horizontal text that wraps to multiple lines*.

Also: note that React Native implements ["limited style inheritance" for text](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#limited-style-inheritance) which differs slightly from the css standard. For example, `<Text>`inherits `color` and 'fontSize`properties only from parent`Text`components, but not`View` components.
Also, the [Flexbox layout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) implementation for React Native differs slightly from the CSS standard.
I don't know if React Native differences affect horizontally centered wrapped text as well, or not.

Comment: Does adding `textAlign: "center"` to the `<Text>`'s style prop work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `textAlign` property like this:

```
<Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>centered Text</Text>
```

You can see the docs for the `textAlign` property here:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalign

Comment: The docs moved, and I proposed an edit to your answer to repair them, but your answer is right on and worked for me. Thanks!