# React Native -- how to horizontally center two Text components when expecting them to wrap to a second line?

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

This post is very close but I do have a different situation: [How to Horizontally Center React Native Flexbox Text that Wraps across Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49949593/how-to-horizontally-center-react-native-flexbox-text-that-wraps-across-multiple)

I am trying to style my text like this: [image] and in order to get the two different text styles to wrap to a second line like that I read I had to wrap the two of them in a `<Text>` container like so:

```
<Text style={textAlign="center"}>
   <Text style={[ {color: colors.mustardYellow, fontSize: 30, textAlign:"center"}, textStyles.Bold]}>Hey! </Text>
   <Text style={[ {color: colors.white, fontWeight: "100", fontSize: 30, textAlign:"center"}]}>How are you feeling today?</Text>
</Text>
```

This worked and lets the second text components wrap under the first one. HOWEVER, it refuses to center itself horizontally on the second line. I tried adding another container around the greater `<text>` component container but did not find any success there either. The only way I was able to make it work was with creating 3 separate text components, one for the yellow text, a second for "How are you" on the first line and a final one for the "feeling today?" on the second line which I was able to center horizontally. This is an awful way to do things and I'm sure there is a right way but for the life of me I cannot find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check out this Snack, it seems to work for me https://snack.expo.io/rkrLCbvLN . If this is not what you're looking for let me know.

Comment: @BrunoEduardo That worked great! I see now how I screwed up the textAlign: "center" on my initial text container. I've been relying on the linter to catch those a lot of the time and I guess it missed that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then, for future readers.

Comment: @Bryan if you find it's wider than desired [working, with the double brackets], consider making a narrower text box or adding a bit of padding/margin to the style. Easy mistake to make..

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks, I think I have the right width for this, but I'll certainly keep that in mind or the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your first `Text` tag your `style` prop sould be `style={{textAlign: "center"}}` instead of `style={textAlign="center"}`.

Here's an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/rkrLCbvLN) with working code.